# how to use WebRequest to Post a file to Website

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

this is my first time writing code that Send WebRequest to website. I am receiving error 403. 
Just wanting someone to look over code and let me know if I am missing something.
Was told we were to use Basic authorization.
here is block of code where I pass file to routine to POST.

```
    Public Sub PostFile(ByVal lFileName As String)  
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://somewebsite.com/jobs/api/inboundjob/?message-type=distributor&format=xml")
    Dim usr As String = "jonesy@somewebsite"
    Dim pwd As String = "1Jw8$PR9Sb"
    Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(usr + ":" + pwd))
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(lFileName)
    Dim postData As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a concrete answer that will solve your problem. But a few tips that may be of help.

**HTTP 403 errors**

The server is forbidding you from accessing this URL. Try looking into the response using a tool like **Fiddler**. Do you see any detailed information?

**How to handle exception messages from WebRequest?**

You will need to handle the *WebException* and get the response out of it. The response is likely to be helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/handling-errors

**About encoding of the HTTP body**

While sending the body of the HTTP request, I would not use *Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes* directly. I would use the *StreamWriter* class and specify the *request.GetDataStream* in the constructor.  **Why?** I cannot be sure about the underlying encoding of the string. Let the Framework classes find out and do the appropriate conversion.

**MSDN documentation and sample code**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class